# Brute Force Created In Python | Numerical Only | Up to 4 Digits

Tags: python, brute-force

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this. I am a tadpole when it comes to write python and right now I just written the framework to create a brute force algo to sort up to 3 digits worth of numbers. Am I in the right direction?

I am assuming the web app actually reveal the number of digits it is send to your email. I first learn about this from TryHackMe.

Now it can randomly create up to 4 digit numbers as seen in BookFace and the above can crack the code as seen using their example. My question is am I doing it in the right way? Because I seen other people's sample of bruteforce and they use a lot of function. Am I being too long winded?

```
import random
digits = 4 #reveal the number of digits 
i=0
z=0
x="" #init password to nothing

#generate random password up to 4 digits
while i < digits:
 z = random.randint(0,9)
 print(z)
 x = str(x) + str(z)
 i+=1
 

y = 1
print("Code Random Generated: " + x)

if digits == 1: 
 while y!=int(x):
  print(y)
  y+=1
elif digits == 2: 
 while y!=int(x):
  if len(str(y)) == 1:
   print("0" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 2:
   print(y)
  y+=1
elif digits == 3: 
 while y!=int(x):
  if len(str(y)) ==1:
   print("00" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 2:
   print("0" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 3:
   print(y)
  y+=1
elif digits == 4: 
 while y!=int(x):
  if len(str(y)) ==1:
   print("000" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 2:
   print("00" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 3:
   print("0" + format(y))
  elif len(str(y)) == 4:
   print(y)
  y+=1  
  
if y !=0:
 print("Reset Code Revealed: " + format(y))
```

Comment: So this prints a sequence from 0001 to the randomly selected number. What is your question? What is the desired output? You talk about sorting, but then what is it supposed to sort?

Comment: Now it can randomly create up to 4 digit numbers as seen in BookFace and the above can crack the code as seen using their example. My question is am I doing it in the right way? Because I seen other people's sample of bruteforce and they use a lot of function. Am I being too long winded?

Comment: I don't see any code cracking here. The program already has the code from the start. I don't see the point. And still, ... what is the sorting about? What is BookFace?

Comment: The code generates up to 4 digit random password which I then trying to use brute force framework to try to churn out and match the random password. But my language seems long winded.

Comment: Yes, but why don't you answer my questions?

Comment: bookface is a fake website mimicking facebook. It is generated by tryhackme.com

There is no sorting in the code? Which line?

Comment: Well your question mentions *"brute force algo to sort"*... I don't understand why you would try to match a number that you already have? I mean, what is wrong with printing `x` instead of looping a counter towards `x`, which you then print, and which is the same as printing `x`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are sort of asking for a code review, not for a problem's solution. This is what [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for.

Anyway, let's look at my own solution to the problem :

```py
"""
An humble try at cracking simple passwords.
"""

import itertools
import random
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Optional


def generate_random_numerical_password(ndigits: int) -> str:
    return "".join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(ndigits))


def guesses_generator(ndigits: int) -> Iterable[str]:
    yield from ("".join(digits) for digits in itertools.product("0123456789", repeat=ndigits))


PasswordOracle = Callable[[str], bool]


def cracker(ndigits: int, oracle: PasswordOracle) -> Optional[str]:
    for guess in guesses_generator(ndigits):
        if oracle(guess):
            return guess
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    NDIGITS = 4  # difficulty
    print(f"the difficulty (number of digits) is set to {NDIGITS}")
    password = generate_random_numerical_password(NDIGITS)
    print(f"the password to crack is {password!r}")
    password_oracle = lambda guess: guess == password  # do not use `is`, see Python's string interning
    if match := cracker(NDIGITS, password_oracle):
        print("Cracked!")
    else:
        print("Error, not found")
```

Some differences :

- The different parts of the program are clearly delimited using functions (password creation and cracking).
- The guess generation is generalized : if the number of digits become 5, you will have to write another (tedious and error-prone) `elif`.
- The "flow" of the program is made very clear in the "main" part : generate a password and the corresponding oracle, call the cracker and check if a result was found. There is very few lines to read, and using descriptive names helped too.
- The names come from the domain ("cracking") : "guess", "difficulty", "generator" instead of abstract ones like "x" and "y".
- Some language knowledge is used : standard types operations (`str`-joining instead of concatenation), generators (`yield from`), libraries (`itertools.product`), syntax (walrus oparetor `if match := cracker(...)`, ...
- There is more documentation : comments, docstring at the top of the module, type annotations, ... all of these helping to understand how the program works.

> My question is am I doing it in the right way? Because I seen other people's sample of bruteforce and they use a lot of function. Am I being too long winded?

I did not do use functions on purpose to do like the others people, but because I see things in a different way than you, which I will try to explain.
In the end, both your solution and mine solve the initial problem "crack a four-digit password". In this way, they are not much different. But there could be other ways to consider :

- Will the problem change ? Could the password be 5 digits, or contain alphabetic characters, or special characters ? In such cases, how long will it take to adapt the script ? This is the malleability of the code.
- How clear is the code ? If I have a bug to fix, how long will it take me to find where it comes from ? What if it is someone new to Python ? Or someone that knows Python well but never saw the code ? This is the maintainability of the code.
- How easy is it to test the code ? What can be tested ? This is teastability.
- How fast is the code ? How much memory does it uses ?  This is performance ?
- Can the program crash ? What if the program is given bad inputs ? Could it cause an infinite loop ? This is program-safety.
- ...

Depending on how your objectives about malleability, maintainability, testability, performance, safety, ... (other qualities of a program), but also depending on the context. who is writing the code ? Who will read it later ? How much experienced they are ? How much time do they have to finish writing it ? Will it be run only once then thrown away or will it be deployed on millions of devices ?
All of that affects how you write it. If I was in your shoes (beginner to Python, writing a run-once-then-forget script) I would have done the same as you. The difference is the context and the objectives. I wrote my code as an example to show you the difference. But neither is good nor bad.
You are not bad at running just because you are slower than an Olympic athlete. You can only be bad relative to a context and objectives. In Physical Education class, you are graded on your running speed according to the average for your age and the progress you made.
Seeing things in their perspective is a very useful skill, not just for programming.

Whan you compare your code to other's, yours seem less "clever", less "clean", less "elegant". But you are comparing apples to oranges. You are not the others. If your solution was accepted (correct and fast enough) that's a good start at your level.
My years of professionnal experience working with several other people on tens-of-thousand-lines codebases that have to be maintained for 20 years are a different set of contexts and objectives than you learning the language in fun ways (TryHackMe). Neither is objectively bad, both are subjectively good.

**TL;DR** : your code is fine for a beginner, you still have lots to learn if you want to, and keep having fun !

Comment: Damn! You are a genius.

Comment: @newbietostack I'm not a genious, but I have a bit of experience (blog reading and professional practice) and I take the time to consider each matter from different directions. For example, often you can read "Python is slow", but it is usually fast *enough* for running a simple script to process a file into another. Yes C would have been marginally faster, but for this script Python was much much easier than C. Everything is both true and false, it always depend of the point-of-view.

Comment: @newbietostack Writing the script was very easy for me : having read the description you wrote and your code, the solution just appeared in my mind and I wrote it in one run. The limiting factor for me was my typing speed (no touch-typing). But 10 years ago I would have needed a few minutes at least to articulate the solution, and some trial-and-error to write it. Skills grow with deliberate practice, but it takes time. As for everything else (cooking, driving a car, writing poetry, ...). But I am baffled by many people better than me, I just don't let me get discouraged :)